# "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" even it's inside a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use ReactHooks `useEffect` inside a function component.
However, it return the error saying that **Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**

My code is like

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
   // call for tracking event 
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
     this is an example
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this exampleCode is a child component of class component. I guess it's not an issue.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
render() {
return <exampleCode />
 }
}
```

react and react DOM version is 16.8.6. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: React components start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: thanks it's my typo

Answer (score 0):

One or two issues. Like others have mentioned, you need to capitalise the name of your component, if you provide it. You can have something like this of course, which forgoes that entirely:

```
export default ({ children }) => {
  ...
};
```

The other thing is, you gave the example where you have useEffect() but there is no useState() there, ie no hook for it to act upon. Shall we assume you omitted that for clarity? If you don't have it, I suspect that's why you are encountering this error.